# Video and Audio Call Option with Permission of Login When Popup With Different Persons on Different pages in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Actually, I want to add Video and Audio Call Options with Permission of Login When Popup...And I want to add those call options for Different Persons on Different pages in Wordpress...
I want something like that 
https://m.idealvoyance.fr/voyance-maryam

Comment: Could you show your effort with examples?

Comment: https://m.idealvoyance.fr/voyance-maryam
Just like that ... I want to show the profile and detail, then the call option and popup while clicking

Comment: http://africavoyance.fr/?page_id=81
I need to implement it here